# Facebook Product Feeds For additional Countries (Dynamic Remarketing)

Tags: facebook

We have created some new product feeds to target additional countries, France, Spain, Germany etc within Facebook. All feeds are in different languages and have uploaded successfully. Although they are not showing products due to product ID's being the same as the UK feed.

Is there away of approving all products in all feeds with the same ID, or do we need to adjust all product ID numbers to make them individual to each feed.

Thanks